# Magento 2 Admin customer form range validation is not working?

Tags: magento-2.1, form-validation

I want to add range validation for mobile , i have added "validation-digits-range" rule in ui component xml. I have declared range as 9-13 and I enter correct 10 digits still asking "The value is not within the specified range."

here is the ui component code

```
<field name="mobile_no">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="validate-digits" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="validate-digits-range" xsi:type="string">9-13</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

here is the screen shot of customer form
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because the validation rule you are using looks like this:

```
    'validate-digits-range': [
        function (value, param) {
            var numValue, dataAttrRange, result, range, m;

            if (utils.isEmptyNoTrim(value)) {
                return true;
            }

            numValue = utils.parseNumber(value);

            if (isNaN(numValue)) {
                return false;
            }

            dataAttrRange = /^(-?\d+)?-(-?\d+)?$/;
            result = true;
            range = param;

            if (range) {
                m = dataAttrRange.exec(range);

                if (m) {
                    result = result && utils.isBetween(numValue, m[1], m[2]);
                }
            }

            return result;
        },
        $.mage.__('The value is not within the specified range.')
    ],
```

as you can see, the `utils.isBetween` code just checks that a whole value of the input field greater than `9` and less than `13`. In your case you should use the custom validation rule or `min_text_length` and `max_text_length` rules.